# How to display all interfaces IPv6/prefix addresses in c

Tags: c, linux, ipv6

I am having troubles displaying all IPv6 addresses in format IPv6/prefix.
How can I do that?
I am using getifaddrs to get all interface IPv6 addresses and then what should I use?

Thanks!

Just roughly showing what I want to achieve:

```
struct ifaddrs *ifa     = NULL;
struct ifaddrs *ifap    = NULL;
int res                 = 0;
void *p                 = NULL;
char addressOutputBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

res = getifaddrs(&ifa);

...

for (ifap = ifa; ifap != NULL; ifap = ifap->ifa_next)   {

    // Filter out by AF
    if (ifap->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_INET6) {
        continue;
    }

    p = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)ifap->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr;

    inet_ntop(ifap->ifa_addr->sa_family, p,addressOutputBuffer,sizeof(addressOutputBuffer));

    // I want to display IPv6/prefix format


}
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: When you say "IPv6/prefix" that suggests that there is a standard you can find by that name for the display format.  I do not see that listed on Wikipedia in the [IPv6 Presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Presentation) or elsewhere as a name for a presentation format.  Google has no leads on that having meaning either.  This is one reason why it's very important for you to show *concrete examples* of the desired output of your program for sample cases.  What strings do you expect to see output?

Comment: If you grab `&((struct sockaddr_in6 *)ifa->ifa_netmask)->sin6_addr`  and step through the 16 bytes of address, beginning from the end, you could count the number of zero bits to get the prefix, then just tack it on to the end of `addressOutputBuffer`.  This is admittedly dirty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to do what you ask is to use the netlink mechanism to get the information you need straight from the Linux kernel.  This avoids the hackery I suggested in an earlier comment, but is not portable.  Pick your poison, I guess.

For more information you can look at the man pages for [netlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) and [rtnetlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html).

On my machine, the following code produces:

`::1/128`

`fe80::222:4dff:fe9d:3dd9/64`

which matches the output of ifconfig.

```
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    char buf[16384];

    // Our message will be a header followed by an address payload
    struct {
        struct nlmsghdr nlhdr;
        struct ifaddrmsg addrmsg;
    } msg;

    struct nlmsghdr *retmsg;

    // Set up the netlink socket
    int sock = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);

    // Fill in the message
    // NLM_F_REQUEST means we are asking the kernel for data
    // NLM_F_ROOT means provide all the addresses
    // RTM_GETADDR means we want the addresses of interfaces
    // AF_INET6 means limit the response to ipv6 addresses
    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    msg.nlhdr.nlmsg_len = NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(struct ifaddrmsg));
    msg.nlhdr.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ROOT;
    msg.nlhdr.nlmsg_type = RTM_GETADDR;
    msg.addrmsg.ifa_family = AF_INET6;

    // Send the netlink message
    send(sock, &msg, msg.nlhdr.nlmsg_len, 0);

    int len;

    // Get the netlink reply
    len = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

    retmsg = (struct nlmsghdr *)buf;

    // Loop through the reply messages (one for each address)
    // Each message has a ifaddrmsg structure in it, which 
    // contains the prefix length as a member.  The ifaddrmsg
    // structure is followed by one or more rtattr structures, 
    // some of which (should) contain raw addresses.
    while NLMSG_OK(retmsg, len) {

        struct ifaddrmsg *retaddr;
        retaddr = (struct ifaddrmsg *)NLMSG_DATA(retmsg);

        struct rtattr *retrta;
        retrta = (struct rtattr *)IFA_RTA(retaddr);

        int attlen;
        attlen = IFA_PAYLOAD(retmsg);

        char pradd[128];

        // Loop through the routing information to look for the 
        // raw address.
        while RTA_OK(retrta, attlen) {
            if (retrta->rta_type == IFA_ADDRESS) {
                inet_ntop(AF_INET6, RTA_DATA(retrta), pradd, sizeof(pradd));
                printf("%s/%u\n", pradd, retaddr->ifa_prefixlen);
            }
            retrta = RTA_NEXT(retrta, attlen);

        }

        retmsg = NLMSG_NEXT(retmsg, len);       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example to display all IPv4/IPv6 addresses by getifaddrs() API.

```
# ip addr show
1: lo: ...
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 ...
    inet6 ::1/128 ...
2: eth0: ...
    inet 10.254.52.242/19 ...
    inet6 fe80::d20d:7bff:feb3:7e41/64 ...

# gcc get_ip.c && ./a.out
lo: 127.0.0.1/8
eth0: 10.254.52.242/19
lo: ::1/128
eth0: fe80::d20d:7bff:feb3:7e41/64

===========================================

# cat get_ip.c

#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>     //exit()
#include <stdio.h>      //printf(),perror()
#include <string.h>     //memset
#include <ifaddrs.h>    //struct ifaddrs,getifaddrs()
#include <arpa/inet.h>  //INET6_ADDRSTRLEN,inet_ntop()
#include <netinet/in.h> //sockaddr_in,sockaddr_in6

void die(char * s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

void print_all_ip()
{
    struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
    char ip_str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) < 0) {
        die("getifaddrs");
    }

    for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
        if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL) { continue; }

        switch (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family) {
            case AF_INET: {
                struct sockaddr_in *a = (struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_addr;
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(a->sin_addr), ip_str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

                uint32_t n = ((struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_netmask)->sin_addr.s_addr;
                int i = 0;
                while (n > 0) {
                     if (n & 1) i++;
                     n = n >> 1;
                }
                printf("%s: %s/%d\n", ifa->ifa_name, ip_str, i);
                break;
            }
            case AF_INET6: {
                struct sockaddr_in6 *a = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)ifa->ifa_addr;
                inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(a->sin6_addr), ip_str, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

                unsigned char *c = ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)ifa->ifa_netmask)->sin6_addr.s6_addr;
                int i = 0, j = 0;
                unsigned char n = 0;
                while (i < 16) {
                    n = c[i];
                    while (n > 0) {
                        if (n & 1) j++;
                        n = n/2;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                printf("%s: %s/%d\n", ifa->ifa_name, ip_str, j);
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    print_all_ip();
    exit(0);
}
```