# Finding tun0 ip address

Tags: openvpn

I'm need to use a Linux cmd to find the ip address range that is assigned to a virtual network interface named tun0 which is being used by openvpn. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: (1) This question would be better suited for Unix & Linux than for Stack Overflow. (2) You can simply parse the output from `ip addr show dev tun0` or, if you want to read it from C, then [`getifaddrs()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) is your friend. (3) A recommendation: OpenVPN is a single-threaded userspace toy; use IPSec if you want a real VPN that performs well and doesn’t require `tun0` or other ugly tricks.

Comment: [Here’s the complete code, including prefix lengths.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48375002/8584929)